# Parskip spacing of a list in a table

Tags: tables, spacing, lists, parskip

I want to undo the following effect of the `parskip` package in a *list environment in a table*:

Without `parskip` the spacing looks nice.

[image: without parskip]

With `parskip` the first line is so uncomfortably close to the line above it. It's not very aesthetic, folks.

[image: with parskip]

Here is my minimal working example (compiled with XeLaTeX)

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|m{8cm} |}
        \hline
        \textbf{Example - list in a table} \\
        \hline
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Yeesh! I hope I'm not too close to the top!           
            \begin{itemize}
                \item I'm right here with ya
            \end{itemize}
            \item Another line        
            \begin{itemize}
                \item below me,
                \item under the sea...
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If there's another package that systematically modifies paragraph indenting and spacing (the reason why I need `parskip`) that does not cause this issue, that would also be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the package `enumitem` you can easily set the spacing in lists like `itemize`.

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{parsep=1ex,topsep=2ex}
```

[image]

Comment: thx! for any onlookers `\setlist[enumerate,...` does the same thing for number lists